# Difference between @singleton and @context in micronuat

Tags: java, micronaut

I have a micronaut application and beans annotated with `@Singleton` are not getting eagerly initialized during application start up. Even setting `eagerInitSingletons` true doesn't help the beans to be initialized at start up.

**Main Class**

```
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Micronaut.build(args)
            .eagerInitSingletons(true)
            .mainClass(Application.class)
            .start();
  }
```

}

**Factory Class**

```
@Factory
public class Config {

  @Singleton
  public ResponseScheduler response() {
    System.out.println("Invoked");
    //invoking some code
    return new ResponseScheduler("test");
   }
}
```

The application start up without executing loading the `ResponseScheduler` bean, this `ResponseScheduler` is from third party library and creating bean will create a scheduler with default config. But this bean is not used in any part of the application, it is just a scheduler to periodically check some functionality.

With `@Singleton` annotation the bean is not getting initialized, is there a way in micronaut to load the bean for running in background.

Answer (score 1):

For loading the bean eagerly we should use [@Context](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/context/annotation/Context.html) annotation, by default all Singleton bean definitions as lazy and will only load them on demand.

> Context scope indicates that the classes life cycle is bound to that of the BeanContext and it should be initialized and shutdown during startup and shutdown of the underlying BeanContext.

> Micronaut by default treats all Singleton bean definitions as lazy and will only load them on demand. By annotating a bean with @Context you can ensure that the bean is loaded at the same time as the context.

> WARNING: This annotation should be used sparingly as Micronaut is designed in such a way as to encourage minimal bean creation during startup.

```
@Factory
public class Config {

  @Context
  public ResponseScheduler response() {
     System.out.println("Invoked");
     //invoking some code
     return new ResponseScheduler("test");
   }
}
```